# How do I get values from dynamic number of child components based on another child component action in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this scenario:

I have a parent component that has a child **ButtonComponent**, and a dynamic number of **InputComponent**s.

***app.component.ts***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  ids = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'g1'] // this part is dynamic

  onSaved(){
    // how do I get all input values here? 
    console.log('saved clicked')
  }
}
```

***app.component.html***

```
<app-button-component (saved)="onSaved()"></app-button-component>
<app-input-component *ngFor="let  id of ids" [id]='id'></app-input-component>
```

The **ButtonComponent** has a button, and when that button is clicked, I'd like to get input values from **InputComponent**s components.

***button-component.component.ts***

```
export class ButtonComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() saved = new EventEmitter()

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  save(){
    this.saved.emit('true')
  }

}
```

***button-component.component.html***

```
<button (click)="save()" >Save</button>
```

Now, this is the InputComponent:

***input-component.component.ts***

```
 export class InputComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id =''
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

***input-component.component.html***

```
<div class="inp">
  <span>{{id}}</span>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="100" />
</div>
```

Now, I understand how to pass the click event from the **ButtonComponent** to the AppComponent, however, I'm not sure what would be a correct approach regarding getting all input values from the **InputComponent**s on button click.

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qrzefv?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-component%2Finput-component.component.html).

I'd appreciate your help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pass a reference variable to the input component:

```
<app-input-component *ngFor="let  id of ids" [id]='id' #inputComp></app-input-component>
```

Note, that we don't need unique reference variables for all of the input components, because `ngFor` does it for us already.

After that we declare the input components like this:

```
  @ViewChildren('inputComp')
  inputComponents: QueryList<InputComponentComponent>;
```

In the input component we declare a `value` variable and bind it to the value of the input element with two way binding:

```
  <input type="number" min="1" max="100" [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

Now, we have proper access to the value of each input component and can log it like this:

```
this.inputComponents.forEach((item) => console.log(item.value));
```

You can find here the forked example: [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ihxspv)